# Unable to install cppyy on Ubuntu — gmake error 2

Tags: python, c++, build, python-wheel, cppyy

I'm trying to install [`cppyy`](https://cppyy.readthedocs.io/) on Ubuntu (arm64) using a Python installation created using [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). `gcc`, `g++`, `build-essential`, and `make` are installed from the default Ubuntu distribution packages.

I have tried two methods to install `cppyy`, but neither seems to be working. **How can I install it successfully?**

### Method 1

```shellsession
$ pip install -v cppyy
```

**Output**: [Link](https://pastebin.com/zRg1mHGM)

### Method 2

```shellsession
$ STDCXX=20 MAKE_NPROCS=32 pip install --verbose cppyy --no-binary=cppyy-cling
```

**Output:** [Link](https://pastebin.com/VLTxUrsp)

Comment: I wouldn't use `MAKE_NPROCS=32` unless you have that many cores, but that aside, any option to lower the C++ standard, e.g. to 17? I.e. `STDCXX=17`? There are CircleCI builds for ARM, so hopefully get binary wheel soon (the final upload isn't functional yet).

Comment: I used both of those options because they are listed as supported in the [install documentation](https://cppyy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)… I think that [the problem is with the ARM architecture itself](https://github.com/wlav/cppyy/issues/150).

Comment: The error linked something specific to Mac M1/M2 that I've not been able to reproduce yet.